# Condense two ternary operators into a single one-liner?

Tags: python

I'm parsing multiple csvs that contain overlapping fields. I'm first trying to check if a field exists in the csv being parsed, and then check if that value exists in a dictionary. If that value doesn't already exist, then I want to append the value to the dictionary, so that I can later write all of the unique values to a separate file. 
I needed to reduce this:

```
if 'ZIPCODE' in row: ZipCode = row['ZIPCODE'].upper()
else: ZipCode = ' '
```

and was directed to ternary operators:

```
ZipCode = row['ZIPCODE'].upper() if 'ZIPCODE' in row else ' '
```

The second check is an if else for the Dict:

```
FieldDict['ZipList'].append(ZipCode) if ZipCode not in FieldDict['ZipList'] else ' '
```

My question is, is there a way to combine those two comparisons into a single statement? Or, is there a better way to check for uniqueness in both the csv and the dictionary.

**** figured it out ****

```
FieldDict['ZipList'].append(row['ZipCode'].upper()) if 'ZipCode' in row else ' ' if row['ZipCode'] not in FieldDict['ZipList'] else ' '
```

Comment: Did you try Googling your question's title?

Comment: Search ternary assignment in Python.

Comment: I like this one: `row.get('ZIPCODE', ' ').upper()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Python ["Conditional Expressions"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
ZipCode = row['ZIPCODE'].upper() if 'ZIPCODE' in row else ' '
```

<s>An other way to simulate ternary operator is:</s>

```
ZipCode = [' ', row['ZIPCODE'].upper()]['ZIPCODE' in row]
```

**Edit:** The second method can not work as 'ZIPCODE' may not be in row, so first list can not be created and an error is raised. It was stupid.

As marcus said, [dictionnary get method()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) is perfect to solve this question.

```
row.get('ZIPCODE', ' ').upper()
```

---

About Kasra comment, here is a little `timeit` showing he is right:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('["No", "Yes"][50 in range(100)]', number=1000000)
2.7500426138772203
>>> timeit.timeit('"Yes" if 50 in range(100) else "No"', number=1000000)
2.2611985253367393
```

Comment: The second is a good idea but i think the first has more performance which hasn't indexing!

Comment: the first one gives me a "can't assign to operator" error and the second one gives me a "was expecting one of...." between the two `][`

Comment: @Delgan I take it back - I had the syntax incorrect.

Comment: @Kasra Indeed. Moreover, the second do not neither need to create lists.

Comment: @Delgan - I unfortunately have to create lists to store a bunch of unique zipcodes (only adding zipcodes if they don't already exists) later on in my code. But, thanks to you all, I'm also using ternary operators for those statements. 
Unless you can think of a way to condense those two checks into a single statement. 
I'm going to edit my original question

Comment: @user2338089 I am not sure it is possible. Why do you need it as a one liner?

Comment: @Delgan because I have a lot (500+) fields to check and it'd keep my code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
zipcode = row['ZIPCODE'].upper() if 'ZIPCODE' in row else ' '
```